# android startup kit

Tags: android

I'm planning to start self-learning of Android development.

What would you guys recommend as the best *starter kit*?

Regarding the target, is it OK to use my own smartphone for testing (besides emulators). Or should I better get a dedicated test target to avoid screwing my phone? Are there common pitfalls or issues that I should be aware of before starting to use my programs on my phone? Or is it simply impossible to upload my app directly to my phone without going through the Android Market?

I realize this question may be considered subjective. I'm looking forward to reading about your experiences though.

Comment: What about making this question a community wiki?

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers. It's been difficult to pick one as better than the others to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started out with some ideas that I wanted to build and by watching this series: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mf7z_mrce00&feature=list_related&playnext=1&list=SPE953C0B85B50AB62

It's a great series that covers some basics as well as some mid-level topics. From there I would recommend building your first application and when you run into an issue you can't figure out, Google it or search on SO.

As for testing on your own phone - It will be difficult to mess up your phone unless you do something completely out there. It's best to use your own phone along with emulators setup with different settings such as resolutions etc.

If you're using Eclipse to develop, you can run the app's directly from the IDE and they will be installed on your phone. Also, you can use adb.exe that comes with the Android SDK to install .apk files directly to your phone.

In my opinion, the best way to get started with Android is to have an idea of an app you want to develop and jump in head first. When you run into an issue, search for the answer - it's probably been done before.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few points that I hope will help you and others in your position:

1. **Use the available tutorials.** The Android Developer site has [a lot of useful resources](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=sample), and there are a lot a other very interesting sites that'll help you getting started and with your questions, i.e. [anddev.org](http://www.anddev.org), [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/) and [Lars Vogel's site](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html).
2. **Give it a go!** Don't be afraid to try it out and mess around with the Android SDK, layouts, activities, etc. I strongly believe that learning by doing is a great way to learn. It's really rather hard to mess up your device - especially if you're not intentionally trying :-)
3. **Use your own devices.** I always use my own personal devices to test out my applications. There are of course cons and pros of both scenarios, but testing on my own device is in my opinion more useful, because it's like a "real world" test instead of a test on a device that's only used for testing.
4. **Local testing is easy.** You can easily set up your own phone to do local testing and debugging. No need to use Android Market for that. If you want, you can however use Market to get beta feedback, just be sure to note that it's unfinished software and that user feedback is highly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

I've always used my own personal phone and never had trouble with it. These days, I test on my own phone and tablet. The emulator is just a bit too slow to be used, except when testing screen resolutions I don't have a device for.

When developing, just always be aware that not all devices are the same. Android is great in that regard, but just be considerate that - for example - not all phones have hardware buttons, and not all phones have big, high-res screens.

You can run your app on your phone without needing to go anywhere near Android Market. The Market is only required if you want to make your app available to the wider audience of people who use Android Market on their phones.

Answer (score 2):

Android SDK is very friendly for starting up Android development. And articles here (as well as documentation) is a must have and available here in [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html)

You cannot really screw up your phone unless you start messing with system services, I usually always do the development testing on my own phone and then test emulators for earlier (and later) versions due to emulators being a little slow.

It is quite easy to upload an app to your phone without Android market, you just have to allow it to install apps from unknown sources as well as turn on USB debugging when phone is connected with USB. When you install SDK you should also install the USB drivers to make the connection work. Some phones, like HTC phones, can have problems with default drivers, if you cannot make it work then grab HTC ADB drivers [here](http://uploads.waher.net/adb_driver_htc.zip)

Answer (score 0):

check this it will helpful

http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.com/2011/04/installing-and-updating-android-on-your.html

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the android market.
You can test on your own phone, that s how I started... of course by testing on it you use more your phone, but it is not worth using it for regular purposes (except intensive computing).